# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderators, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Photography breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1          8
Users destroyed                                  11          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   4          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            49        897
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                4        165
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          7      1,033
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                4        625
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                11      2,214
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                8      2,869
Questions reopened                               17         12
Questions protected                               2         42
Questions migrated                               21          0
Questions merged                                  3          0
Questions flagged⁴                                6      1,076
Questions closed                                 70        792
Question flags handled⁴                         261        821
Posts unlocked                                    5          3
Posts undeleted                                  34         38
Posts locked                                      3         86
Posts deleted⁵                                  562      1,128
Posts bumped                                      0        494
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               23          0
Comments flagged                                  4      1,567
Comments deleted⁶                             1,781      2,751
Comment flags handled                           805        766
Answers flagged                                  15      1,856
Answer flags handled                          1,562        309
All comments on a post moved to chat              7          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...